# Reverse DNS for mail server

Tags: email, dns

I have a domain name, `gloomy-zone.ovh`, so at the French company OVH.

I have set up a self-hosted mail server.

I configured the DNS zone for my mail server, but I can't set up reverse DNS, PTR Resource Record not available in the OVH assistant.

OVH Support told me that their server is mutualised, so I can't configure reverse DNS.

That is embarrassing for the deliverability of my emails.

Is there a (free) solution to my problem?

Is it that I need to implement a self-hosted DNS server?

Comment: You should [merge your accounts](http://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts) so you can comment on your own question.

Answer (score 1):

RDNS should be configured on your ISP not your domain name, unless your Domain name is managed by the ISP as well.

If you are unable to have your ISP configure a RDNS entry for you then your best solution would be to Smart-Host to your ISP's Mail server for external mail delivery or a 3rd party Mail Relay service.